# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ is divergent if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are both convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In my practice midterm there is a multiple choice question that I thought was relatively straight forward but the solutions gave an answer that was unexpected to me.

**Question:** If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are convergent series, which of the following is **not** necessarily true?

**(A)**$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ is convergent

**(B)**$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ = ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$) + ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$)

**(C)**$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-b_n)$ = ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$) - ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$)

**(D)**$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ca_n$=$c\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ for any constant *c*

**(E)**$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ is divergent (assuming $a_n\ne0$ for all *n*)

I understand why options B, C & D are true given the Algebraic Properties of Convergent Series and I thought that A is true as well. However, the solutions say that the correct answer is A.

Is there any proof that holds E to be true and under what situations would A be false in this scenario?

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: Hint:  To see a counterexample for $(A)$, suppose both $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ alternate signs, but that the product $\{a_nb_n\}$ is strictly positive.

Comment: For $(A)$ is essential keep $a_n, b_n$ sign or not.

Comment: (A) could be false. Take $a_n=b_n=(-1)^n /\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused because A is *almost* true. If either of $\sum a_n$ or $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum a_n b_n$ does converge. This indicates that you have to use some series with alternating signs, which suggests using a series that converges by the alternating series test, like Jens suggested.

Comment: As @IzaakvanDongen said, I mistakenly assumed that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge absolutely. After working it out, I understand what went wrong in my thinking. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent then there exists $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} a_n=0$, hence $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}=\infty$ and $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_n}$ cannot be convergent (assuming $a_n\ne0$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$).

So (E) is necessarily true.

But (A) is not necessarily true, indeed $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\;$ and $\;\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty b_n=(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}\;$ are convergent, but $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n=\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is divergent.

Comment: Hmm. It's not quite right to say that we must have $1 / a_n \to \infty$, because the $a_n$ can be negative, or can alternate signs. It's true that $\lvert 1 / a_n \rvert \to \infty$, which implies $1 / a_n \not \to 0$, which is what we need.

Comment: When I write that the result of a limit is $\infty$, I do not mean $+\infty$ but I mean that the sequence takes larger and larger values (positive or negative) as $n$ tends to infinite.

Comment: This is very non-standard, and you should either mention this explicitly, or use the usual notation like I suggested: $\lvert 1 / a_n \rvert \to \infty$. "Tends to $\infty$" has a technical and almost universally agreed upon definition. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Infinite_limits

Comment: Well, I have just said what I mean when I write that a limit is $\infty$ and, according to it, it is correct that $a_n\to0\implies\frac{1}{a_n}\to\infty.$ $\text{I am using the following definition:}\\ x_n\to\infty\text{ means that }\\ \forall M>0\;\exists \nu\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\wedge n>\nu\text{ results } |x_n|>M.$

Answer (score 0):

Talking about E, if a series converges then the corresponding sequence must converge to $0$ . So clearly it's reciprocal will not converge to 0 ( infact it will diverge to  infinity).
Now for A, if you consider an and bn both to be $\dfrac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$. They both converge by alternating series test. but the product is $1/n$ which clearly diverges. You can very easily check that this sequence satisfies the required conditions of the alternating series test.
Ps : if you consider two absolutely convergent series then their product does indeed converge.